# Django call script in view from template

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a view, that displays entries from one date to another, about a certain project. The project model is called "DNN" and times on there are in the "Vnos" model.

views.py:

```
def po_nalogu(request, dnn = None):
dnn = None

form = PregledDNNForm(
    request.GET or None,
)
from_date = get_month_start(timezone.now())
to_date = from_date + relativedelta(months=1)
if request.GET:
    if form.is_valid():
        from_date, to_date, dnn = form.save()
entries_qs = Vnos.objects.filter(dna__dns__dnn = dnn)

month_entries = entries_qs.timespan(from_date, to_date=to_date).order_by('start_time')
sestevek = 0
for entry in month_entries:
    sestevek = sestevek + entry.hours

template = 'porocila/po_nalogu.html'
context = {
    'form' : form,
    'from_date': from_date,
    'to_date': to_date - relativedelta(days=1),
    'entries': month_entries,
    'sestevek' : sestevek,
}

return render(request, template, context=context)
```

Now, I want to add a conditional sentence, so I could print PDF. Is there a way to add something like:

```
if request.method == "PDF"
    do code
```

and in template:

```
<form action="" method="PDF">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I don't want to do a separate view for the PDF file, because of the from and to dates, as it is a lot of computing one more time.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the trouble, with POST Method, because GET method overrode my arguments from previus form in the template. Previus arguments were from_date and to_date. That means GET method with action="?pdf" would set everything else to blank, and add "?pdf".

This however worked perfectly.

template:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="pull-right">
{% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit"> PDF</button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
if request.POST:
    context = {
        'request' : request,,
        'from_date': from_date,
        'to_date': to_date - relativedelta(days=1),
    }
    html_string = render_to_string("pdf.html", context)
    html = HTML(string = html_string)
    pdf = html.write_pdf()
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = 'application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="FILENAME.pdf"
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

mmm, if you want to send a custom parameter you could do something like this:

```
<form method="GET" action="/path/to/action/?pdf">
```

Then in the view you just check:

```
request.GET.get('pdf', '')
```

Comment: Yes I tried that, but did not work. The reason behind that is that I pass the arguments of form, which is included in the template through GET method. The arguments are from_date and to_date. That means after the action with ?pdf, it all gets reset.